# UWP: VS Designer Error when DesignViewModel is inheriting from reactiveui's ReactiveObject

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, viewmodel, uwp, reactiveui

Dear C# reactiveui community,

I am currently developping a UWP-App. To connect the UI with my BusinessLogic, I am using reactiveui in my ViewModels.

However, the VisualStudio designer keeps telling me that there is an error in my XAML when I set the DataContext or the d:DataContext to a ViewModel that extends ReactiveObject.

I keep seeing that nasty prompt to check for errors in my XAML code. The spot where I set my DataContext is underlined.

I am running Debug x86, targetting Build 10240. Experimenting with other Build targets or switching to Release did not help. To make use of the designer, I have to switch to x64 because there are no design instances in x64. That is an unacceptable solution, however.

Anybody who can help me with that issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I can't help with the ReactiveUI issues, but for Visual Studio 2015 you can now toggle the designer so that it does not run code in design mode. We enforce this when you switch to X64 or ARM as targets (since we can not run that code on X86) - which is why the designer then functions.

You can also toggle to 'no project code mode' using the icon next to the zoom control under the designer. Click this icon and VS2015 will no longer run code in the designer and will also show placeholder data for your bindings. Let us know if this feature helps you.